# FOR loop for extracting strings from a dataframe in R

Tags: r

Hope the formatting is correct, this is my first question here.

This is the code:

```
a<-c("alice", "bob", "chris")
b<-c("Ally", "Billy", "Chaz")
c<-c("Arnice", "Brandon", "Charles")
df1<-data.frame(a,b,c)
df2<-c("0","0","0")
df2<-data.frame(df2)
for (n in nrow(df1)) {
df2[[n,1]]<-df1[[n,n]]
}
print(df2)
```

In other words I'm looking to get the strings along the diagonal of the dataframe df1 (I need to do something more complicated, so I'm looking for a general answer), and writing the result to df2.  So the result I want is a vector that says alice, Billy, Charles.  But instead I get a vector that says 0,0,NA.

What am I doing wrong?  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Originally I had single brackets, i.e. df2[n,1]<-df1[n,n].  In desperation I changed it to double brackets even though I knew I would get the same result (which I did).

Answer (score 3):

Use the `diag` function after converting your `data.frame` to a `matrix`:

```
diag(as.matrix(df1))
# [1] "alice"   "Billy"   "Charles"
```

Assuming your data are square (same number of rows and columns) you could manually do this with something like:

```
df1[cbind(1:nrow(df1), seq_len(ncol(df1)))]
```

---

#### Update: Some problems with your present code

In your present code, you are using double brackets (`[[`) and `factors`, both of which would create problems.

Compare with below, where I added `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` when creating the empty "df2", and converted the output to characters using `as.character`:

```
df2 <- c("0","0","0")
df2 <- data.frame(df2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

for (n in seq_len(nrow(df1))) {
  print(df1[n, n])
}
# [1] alice
# Levels: alice bob chris
# [1] Billy
# Levels: Ally Billy Chaz
# [1] Charles
# Levels: Arnice Brandon Charles

for (n in seq_len(nrow(df1))) {
  df2[n, 1] <- as.character(df1[n, n])
}
df2
#       df2
# 1   alice
# 2   Billy
# 3 Charles
```